# Data not shown on UI despite Http Service getting Called

Tags: angular, typescript

Call doesnt work due to upgrades in RXjs version 6 is incorporated in angular version8.
for complete source code see:-
https://github.com/ankit01122/CRUDApp

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ServicexampleService} from './servicexample.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'CRUDApp';
  heroes: object;

  constructor(private serviceExample: ServicexampleService) {
    this.heroes = serviceExample.returnABC();
  }
  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroes = this.serviceExample.returnABC();
  }
}

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServicexampleService {
  private httpClient: HttpClient;
  private abc: Observable<object>;

  constructor( httpClient: HttpClient ) {
    this.abc =  httpClient.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
      }

 public returnABC = (): Observable<object> => this.abc;
}
```

Service should get executed and get data on http://localhost:4200/

Comment: What isn't working? What error are you getting?

Comment: You will need to `.subscribe()` to your observable

Comment: @xdecdec :- No Data is displayed on screen.We can't post images here otherwise had shown to you.

Comment: https://imgur.com/mUSzdoH

Comment: closign this task as resolved. {heroes | json} solved this task.

Comment: marking as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to subscribe to your observable or it wont work.

```
this.serviceExample.returnABC().subscribe(
    data => {
        this.heroes = data;
    }
)
;
```

Comment: Its better to use the async pipe in template.

Comment: changes done as shown in https://github.com/ankit01122/CRUDApp/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts service is also getting called but data not populating.

Comment: You are still assigning this.heroes to the observable. You don't need to do this as you are now subscribing to the result and assigning the data returned to this.heroes.

Comment: still same result...updated file please see https://github.com/ankit01122/CRUDApp/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Are you calling getHeroes() after, because you may be overwriting the heroes variable? Also i would remove your service call from the constructor and put it in ngOnInit. This is the suggested practice in the angular docs.

Comment: i even moved the calling code to ngOnInit but with no success.

Comment: https://imgur.com/mUSzdoH

Comment: can you fork this small project and run on your local ?

Answer (score 0):

Observables are lazy and they will not execute unless you ask them to.
You can do it in two ways.
One is to subscribe as in Sam's reply.

Or use `async` pipe to do the job for you. Async pipe will automatically unsubscribe while when you do subscribe you should take care of the un-subscribe part yourself. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#observable

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to call http in constructor.

Instead it is a better practice to inject http in your constructor and then make the request inside your method. Every httpClient call returns an Observable so in order to retrieve the response you have to subscribe to it.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServicexampleService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient ) {

   }

 public returnABC(): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.get<any>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1);
 }
}



import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ServicexampleService} from './servicexample.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'CRUDApp';
  heroes: object;

  constructor(private serviceExample: ServicexampleService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
      // in case you want to get heroes on init
      this.getHeroes()
  }
  getHeroes(): void {
    this.serviceExample.returnABC().subscribe(response => {
            this.heroes = response;
        });
  }
}
```